# Using Baggage with openTelemetry (Java) automaton tools

Tags: open-telemetry

Please consult adding some extra information to trace (span's) when using openTelemetry javaagent for instrumentation.

Can I use the Baggage API for this?
https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api/1.0.0/io/opentelemetry/api/baggage/package-summary.html
https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api/1.0.0/io/opentelemetry/api/baggage/Baggage.html

Are there any other better ways?

Could anyone share their experience please?

Answer (score 0):

> Please consult adding some extra information to trace (span's)

You are probably looking to use span operations for enriching the span data. There are number of operations you could perform on span such as adding attributes, adding events, and recording exception etc. Please look at the specification for full list of ops https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/api.md#span-operations. Small snippet to demonstrate to operations.

```java
...
...
Tracer tracer = openTelemetrySdk.getTracer("TracerExample");
Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("mySpanName").startSpan();
span.setAttribute("user.id", "ENS1001");
span.setAttribute("cart.items.count", 10);
...
...

Attributes eventAttributes = Attributes.of(stringKey("someKey"), "someCustomValue");
span.addEvent("Completed", eventAttributes)
span.end();
...
```

Javadoc reference for span https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api-trace/latest/io/opentelemetry/api/trace/Span.html.

Comment: Srikanth Chekuri, thank you! But I am using the openTelemetry javaagent for automation.